# Vector Layer Symbol (ism) properties?

Tags: qgis, python, color, vector-grid

I would like to streamline the render of a polygon grid vector layer as a simple line (no fill) via Python coding. I am I bit confused by the implementation referenced by the API.

Is it possible to resolve some simple examples?

Here is my first blind go at implementation (currently non-functioning) -

```
symbol_gridLayer = layer.rendererV2().symbols()[0].changeSymbolLayer(0, QgsSimpleLineSymbolLayerV2(black, 2)
```